# How to get new Set from array of arrays by using Array.map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, array-map

Exploring Sets now and could not get a new Set from an array of x arrays in it.
I what to use Array.map method inside new Set().

Here is what I'm trying to do, and it seems logical, but in the end having values only from the 1st array:

```
new Set(...array.map(x => x.value));
```

Will be awesome to understand what I am doing wrong and how it should look like

**Update**:
To be more clear in my need:

```
const array = [[1,1,3,4], [2,2,3,4], [1,1,3,5]];
new Set(...array.map(x => x));
```

My goal to have `[1,2,3,4,5]` but getting `[1,3,4]`

**Solution**:

```
 new Set(array.map(x => x.value).flat())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only the array, not spreaded parameters:

```
new Set(array.map(x => x.value));
```

From [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> new Set()
> new Set(iterable)
> ```

With a nested array, you need a flat it first:

```js
const
    array = [[1, 1, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 3, 5]],
    unique = new Set(array.flat()),
    result = [...unique].sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(...unique); // still a set
console.log(...result); // array, sorted
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe incorrectly described my goal.
I think that will be better:
`const array = [[1,1,3,4], [2,2,3,4], [1,1,3,5]];
new Set(...array.map(x => x));`
I want `[1,2,3,4,5]` in the end, but getting `[1,3,4]`.